# Send Intent to App in Emulator

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator, adb

Is it somehow possible to send automated intents to an app inside an emulator for testing?

I have a list of all my intents and I want to test them automaticily, so is it possible to just do a `adb shell <myfancycommand> android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` to initiate the `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` action on the device? Or do I have to write a script that calls all the stuff by its own, so for example for this intent install a dummy apk on the device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even more simple is the use of the `am` application.

You can just run it like this from the adb shell:

```
# am broadcast android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE }
Broadcast completed: result=0
# am broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

Comment: it is `am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` in order to work properly (send it as the action and not as the data)

Comment: It is not working. I've tried ```adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED``` and got ```Security exception: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED from pid=8100, uid=2000```

Answer (score 0):

Found this APK: http://isecpartners.com/mobile-security-tools/intent-fuzzer.html it does send null values to the apps to see if they are failing. Because the Source is available you can easily change it to some random value and see if you get some respond!