# Sending intent to BroadcastReceiver from adb

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, adb

I've got BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final String tag = "Intent Intercepter";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String data = intent.getStringExtra("sms_body");
            Log.i(tag, data);
            Toast.makeText(context, data.subSequence(0, data.length()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Intercepted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And also in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.whereismywifeserver.IntentReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But when I try to send intent from adb, I receive error:

```
$ adb shell am start 
-a com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST
--es sms_body "test from adb" 
-c android.intent.category.HOME 
-n com.whereismywifeserver/.IntentReceiver
Starting: Intent { act=com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST t=[android.intent.category.HOME] cmp=com.whereismywifeserver/.IntentReceiver (has extras) }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.whereismywifeserver/com.whereismywifeserver.IntentReceiver} does not exist.
```

When I create intent in code, everything works fine. So how can I send intent from adb?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send Intent to App in Emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277796/send-intent-to-app-in-emulator)

Comment: did you finally find her?

Answer (score 115):

You need not specify receiver. You can use adb instead.

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST 
--es sms_body "test from adb"
```

For more arguments such as integer extras, see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#IntentSpec).

Comment: For some reason broadcast can't reach receiver if string extra (`test from adb` in above example) contain whitespaces. Otherwise it works.

Comment: I have the same issue as @user2137020

Comment: It turns out, you do need `-n com.whereismywifeserver/.IntentReceiver` if you want the string extra.

Comment: Is there a way to send broadcast like this with flags ?

Comment: @iammrmehul - Docs says to use -f with flags, but I'm not sure how that looks...

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#IntentSpec

Comment: @user2137020 - You need to escape the quotes, so they get transferred from the system shell to adb shell. The following works: ```adb shell am broadcast -a com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST 
--es sms_body \"test from adb\"```

Comment: Is there a way to target one emulator (if multiple connected) with this command? e.g. `adb shell -e emulator-5556 am broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETE` ? FYI this command doesn't work. Gives an `error: more than one device/emulator`

Answer (score 45):

The true way to send a broadcast from ADB command  is :

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST --es sms_body "test from adb"
```

And, `-a` means **ACTION**, `--es` means to send a **String** extra.

---

PS. There are other **data type** you can send by specifying different params like:

```
[-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE> ...]
[--esn <EXTRA_KEY> ...]
[--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE> ...]
[--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE> ...]
[--el <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE> ...]
[--ef <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE> ...]
[--eu <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_URI_VALUE> ...]
[--ecn <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME_VALUE>]
[--eia <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_INT_VALUE...]]
    (mutiple extras passed as Integer[])
[--eial <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_INT_VALUE...]]
    (mutiple extras passed as List<Integer>)
[--ela <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_LONG_VALUE...]]
    (mutiple extras passed as Long[])
[--elal <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_LONG_VALUE...]]
    (mutiple extras passed as List<Long>)
[--efa <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE...]]
    (mutiple extras passed as Float[])
[--efal <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE...]]
    (mutiple extras passed as List<Float>)
[--esa <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_STRING_VALUE...]]
    (mutiple extras passed as String[]; to embed a comma into a string,
     escape it using "\,")
[--esal <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_STRING_VALUE...]]
    (mutiple extras passed as List<String>; to embed a comma into a string,
     escape it using "\,")
[-f <FLAG>]
```

For example, you can send an int value by:

```
--ei int_key 0
```

Answer (score 35):

I've found that the command was wrong, correct command contains "broadcast" instead of "start":

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST --es sms_body "test from adb" -n com.whereismywifeserver/.IntentReceiver
```

Answer (score 10):

Using Android 8 and above with added implicit receivers restrictions, you should add a package name of your app at the end of a terminal command:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a my.app.package.TEST my.app.package
```

In case if you have a suffix in debug mode for your package, use `my.app.package.debug` instead.

Comment: Thank you!! I added package name at the end of the command and it started to work)))

Answer (score 9):

As many already noticed, the problem manifests itself only if the extra string contains whitespaces.

The root cause is that OP's host OS/shell (i.e. Windows/cmd.exe) mangles the entered command - the `"` characters get lost, `--es sms_body "test from adb"` becomes `--es sms_body test from adb`. Which results in `sms_body` string extra getting assigned the value of `test` and the rest of the string becoming `<URI>|<PACKAGE>|<COMPONENT>` specifier.

To avoid all that you could use:

```
adb shell "am broadcast -a com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST --es sms_body 'test from adb' -n com.whereismywifeserver/.IntentReceiver"
```

or just start the interactive `adb shell` session first and run the `am broadcast` command from inside of it.

Answer (score 8):

Another thing to keep in mind: Android 8 limits the receivers that can be registered via manifest (e.g., statically)

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Answer (score 7):

Noting down my situation here may be useful to somebody,

I have to send a custom intent with multiple intent extras to a broadcast receiver in Android P,

The details are,

Receiver name: `com.hardian.testservice.TestBroadcastReceiver`

Intent `action = "com.hardian.testservice.ADD_DATA"`

intent extras are,

1. "text"="test msg",
2. "source"= 1,

Run the following in command line.

```
adb shell "am broadcast -a com.hardian.testservice.ADD_DATA --es text 'test msg' --es source 1 -n com.hardian.testservice/.TestBroadcastReceiver"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and found out that you have to escape spaces in the extra:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST --es sms_body "test\ from\ adb"
```

So instead of "test from adb" it should be  "test\ from\ adb"

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether anyone faced issues with getting the whole string "test from adb". Using the escape character in front of the space worked for me.

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST --es sms_body "test\ from\ adb" -n com.whereismywifeserver/.IntentReceiver
```