# Send Intent with Extras From ADB over TCPIP to Android Device

Tags: android, android-intent, adb, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I've sent intents without extras to my SyncReceiver(BroadcastReceiver) successfully using

`adb -s <ip_address> shell am broadcast -a com.istock.ALERT`

However when I add extras the OnReceive event of SyncReceiver is never called, an example of sending an intent with extras

`adb -s <ip_address> shell am broadcast -a com.istock.ALERT --es title "Alert Title"`

I found a [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634446/sending-intent-to-broadcastreceiver-from-adb) with pretty much the same issue, however when I implement the fix it still doesn't call the OnReceive event of the SyncReceiver

`adb -s <ip_address> shell am broadcast -a com.istock.ALERT -n com.istock/.SyncReceiver --es title "Alert Title"`

At this point I just don't understand why I can receive intents without extras sent via adb and am unable to receive intents with extras any idea?

Comment: start the shell first `adb -s <ip_address> shell` then run your `am broadcast` command

Comment: You're a g that worked thanks a bunch

Comment: see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50748795/1778421

Comment: Again thank you, this is going to make it so much easier to incorporate into a Mobile Device Management Application.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was cause by using the command in one line, once I separated the command into 2 parts it worked as intended.

ORIGINAL:

```
adb -s <ip_address> shell am broadcast -a com.istock.ALERT --es title "Alert Title"
```

WORKING:

```
adb -s <ip_address> shell

am broadcast -a com.istock.ALERT --es title "Alert Title"
```

ULTIMATE SOLUTION:

I really wanted to be able to do this in one line (it would make it easier to work into a Mobile Device Management (MDM) Application. Thanks to @Alex P. for his answer [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634446/sending-intent-to-broadcastreceiver-from-adb/50748795#50748795).

ADB seems to mangle the strings encapsulated in Double Quotes ("") a work around he suggests works, just use single quotes ('').

```
adb -s <ip_address> shell am broadcast -a com.istock.ALERT --es title 'Alert Title' --es message 'Alert Message'
```